# optimize number of redis connections with a node.js-application

Tags: node.js, sockets, redis

I have a question about redis connections.

I'm developing an app in react native which will use websockets for chat messages. My backend consists of a node.js-app with redis as pubsub mechanism for socket.io.

I'm planning on deploying on heruko. I'm currently on the free hobby plan, which has a limit of 20 connections to redis.

My question now is: how can I optimize my code so that a minimum of connections are used. I'm ofc planning to upgrade my heroku plan once I launch, but then still I want to optimize.

My node.js-code looks like this (simplified):

```
const Redis = require('ioredis');

const pubClient = new Redis(/* redis url */);
const subClient = new Redis(/* redis url */);
const socketClient = new Redis(/* redis url */);

const io = require('socket.io')(server);

io.on('connection', async (socket) => {
  // store socket.id in redis so I can send messages to individual users
  // based on the user ID
  const userId = socket.handshake.query.userId;
  await socketClient.hset('socketIds', userId, socket.id);

  socket.on('message', async (data) => {
    /**
     * data {
     *  userId,
     *  message
     * }
     */
    const data2 = JSON.parse(data);
    // get the socket.id based on the user ID
    const socketId = await socketClient.hget('socketIds', data2.userId);
    
    // send the message to the correct socket.id
    io.to(socketId).emit('message', data.message); 
 };
});
```

So when I deploy this code to heroku, when started, it will create 3 connections to the same redis server. But what if 2-3-4-... people connect to this node.js-server? If 2 people connect, will there be 6 redis-connections, or only 3? Like: will the node.js-server initiate every time a users accesses the server 3 new redis connections, or will it always be 3 connections?

I'm trying to track all connections with CLIENT LIST in redis-cli, but I does not give me the correct thing I guess. I was just testing my code with only one user connection to the socket server and it gave me 1 client in redis (instead of 3 connections).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter how many people are using the app, each client instance will have only 1 socket at any time, which means you'll see at most 3 clients per node process.

You see only 1 connection because by default `ioredis` initiates the connection when the first command is executed, and not when the client is created. You can call `client.connect()` in order to initiate the socket without executing a command.